# Firebase Connections drop and don't re-sync on android web app

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am having a problem under the following circumstances:
  1.  Running a webapp with both firebase sdk and angularfire initiated connections
  2.  App has been running in background.  Meaning user has launched other apps.  During that time,  internet connectivity could have come and gone.
  3.  User brings webapp back into foreground as active app.  Firebase connectivity via angularfire has been lost and updates have been lost as well.  Hence "2way" binds to existing views/controllers are not longer current and will not re-establish/sync.  Only recovery is to actively kill the app and restart.

This is obviously undesirable.  I have currently attempted a bruit force method where I am issuing a goOnline() call at the beginning of each of my controllers in an attempt to always try to re-establish a connection but for services that expect a 2way bind, I am not sure that everything will sync up?

Any thought or guidance on this would be very helpful as this is a serious issue.

Comment: Can you share specific code that reproduces your problem, in a small digestible sample, with the error messages you are encountering? Otherwise, wildly speculative replies about networking and possible code strategies are the best that can be hoped for a sophisticated issue like this.

Comment: Kato -- let me ask you another question.  Has firebase been tested in an html5 webapp that has been downloaded by the user to the homescreen and is launched, then is put in the background by the user switching to another app?  If you understand the problem then you would realize that your response is not reasonable either.  Basically your are asking me to build a simple htm5 webapp and then try to recreate the issue.  Firebase is advertised as handling connection states.  I am a paying customer.  If it makes more sense I will reach out to Andrew

Comment: Eric, my goal isn't to offend on underestimate the sophistication of this issue. "A smallish sample" simply means some code to demonstrate how you're utilizing goOnline/goOffline/connecting, etc. There's a lot of ground to cover here. Perhaps reaching out to support@firebase.com and opening up a dialog is the best option.

Comment: Ok.  I understand the need for certain issues for code samples but it gets a bit tiring that every time someone posts a question, you always get the same response.  Recreating connectivity related issues can't simply be recreating by posting code.  Instead,  I asked if a specific scenario has been tested.  If the answer is no then I would say it should have been.  I am using firebase in a mobile webapp.  Not an unusual setup but maybe not the typical use.  I can contact support directly but it always seems to me that there is a pervasive attitude that I should have used SO first.